# setTimeout function in useEffect outputs a cached state value

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, settimeout

It's simple.
I'm using Redux to manage my state

I have a `setTimeout` function in a `useEffect` function.

The `setTimeout` has a timeout value of `50000`ms.

## What I Want The SetTimeout Handler To Do

After `50000ms` the `setTimeout` function checks if an api call response has been recieved yet.

If the response hasn't been received yet, the `setTimeout` function should reinitiate the api call because then the call would have been deemed as timedout.

## What The Callback Handler Is Doing

After `50000ms`, the setTimeout handler still reinitiates the api call even though the response has been recieved.

I tried logging the output of the state and then it returned a cached state even though the state was passed to the dependency array of the `useEffect` function and should have been updated

After the api call has been made, the `testDetails.isUpdatingTestDetails` state is set to `false`

I tried out several logics and none of them are working

## Logic 1

```
 useEffect(() => {
         //Notice how i check if the testDetails is being updated before initiating the setTimeout callback
        if (testDetails.isUpdatingTestDetails === true) {
         
            setTimeout(() => {
// Inside the settimeout function the same check is also done.
// even though before 50 seconds the response is being received , the function logs the text simulating the reinitiation of an api call
                return testDetails.isUpdatingTestDetails === true &&
                    console.log("After 50 Seconds You Need To Refetch This Data")
            }, 50000);
        }
 

    }, [testDetails.isUpdatingTestDetails, testDetails])
```

## Logic 2

```
     useEffect(() => {
         setTimeout(() => {
           return testDetails.isUpdatingTestDetails === true &&
             console.log("After 50 Seconds You Need To Refetch This Data")
            }, 50000);
    }, [testDetails.isUpdatingTestDetails, testDetails])
```

None of the logic i've applied above are working.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Reason for stale state:**

The `useEffect`'s callback forms a closure over the state at that time. So, when the timeout's callback gets executed it can only use the old state even if the state is updated in the meantime.

Once the state changes, `useEffect` will run again (as the state is a dependency) and start a new timeout.

The second timeout will use the new state as the closure is formed with the new state. This timeout is also vulnerable to the stale state issue if the state changes for the third time.

---

**Solution:**

You can just clear the previous timeout when the state changes. This way, a timeout's callback won't be executed unless it is the latest.

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(state);
    }, 5000);

    return () => {
      // clears timeout before running the new effect
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>State: {state.toString()}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setState(false)}>update</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit fast-leaf-zk3yo]

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(state);
    }, 5000);

    return () => {
      // clears timeout before running the new effect
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>State: {state.toString()}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setState(false)}>update</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

---

Alternative solution if you want to run the timeout without increasing the delay. If the state changes after the delay, this will not start a new timeout.

You can use `useRef` hook to have a reference to the latest state at all times.

Here's an example. You can modify the following to use your variables and logic.

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(true);
  const stateRef = useRef(state);

  // this effect doesn't need any dependencies
  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      // use `stateRef.current` to read the latest state instead of `state`
      console.log(stateRef.current);
    }, 5000);

    return () => {
      // just to clear the timeout when component unmounts
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, []);

  // this effect updates the ref when state changes
  useEffect(() => {
    stateRef.current = state;
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>State: {state.toString()}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setState(false)}>update</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit charming-sinoussi-tmeo2]

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useRef } = React;

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(true);
  const stateRef = useRef(state);

  // this effect doesn't need any dependencies
  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      // use `stateRef.current` to read the latest state instead of `state`
      console.log(stateRef.current);
    }, 5000);

    return () => {
      // just to clear the timeout when component unmounts
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, []);

  // this effect updates the ref when state changes
  useEffect(() => {
    stateRef.current = state;
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>State: {state.toString()}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setState(false)}>update</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hi. Okay Your Solutions Seems To Work but not entirely.
However this is the first time i'm using useRef.

I have several questions.

1) Why is the useEffect function responsible for logging the current stateRef having no dependency.
2) I can clearly see that you update the stateRef anytime the state changes but even though it gets updated, the logging function inside the useEffect function doesn't run.
Is it because you passed no dependencies to the useEffect handling the logging or it's something else.

Comment: @FreduahGideon The second solution is something you can use if you want to run the timeout only once while making sure that the timeout uses the latest state. It has access to the latest state even with zero dependencies because the state's value is accessed from the ref and this ref is persisted until the component unmounts.

Comment: @FreduahGideon the first solution is recommended if you want to restart a 50s timeout after the state change.

Comment: Well Thank You Very Much.
Your Solution Solved My Problem.
After some minor tweaks, i got what i wanted